# RUBY: How can I print only the words that start with a certain letter from an Array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

-------So what I have so far is-----------

```
array = ["milk", "bread", "pizza", "eggs", "soda", "beer"]

def first_letter(x)
  if x.start_with?(b)
     puts x
  end
end

first_letter(array)
```

Really confused on what I need to do. I've checked Ruby Docs and I still can't figure out how to **single out just the words that start with "B" in my array and print them to the screen**. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `x.start_with?("b")` ⇐ note quotes around `"b"`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: yes, and x should be element of the array, not array itself :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev oh, indeed :)

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is basically select the elements, matching the condition.

To this end you can use [Array#`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
array.select { |word| word.start_with?('b') }
#=> ["bread", "beer"]
```

Comment: Could you please expand the answer to contain explanation of the functions, and specifically select?

Comment: @FrederikSpang, sure on it :)